# Does locally Lipschitz in x, uniformly w.r.t. t imply that $f_{n}(x):=f(x,t_{n})$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f$ satisfies
[image]

**Question**

- Let $t_{n}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_{n}=t_{0}$. Does the sequence $f_{n}(x):=f(x,t_{n})$ converge uniformly to $f(x,t_{0})$?
- I would like to know if this is the case, because I am trying to understand when I can interchange $\lim$ and $\int$. If the above is true, then I think I could use the Lebesgue convergence theorem to show that $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} \int f=\int\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f$.
- What also puzzles me is that I have found a proof of $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} \int f=\int\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f$ that uses only the locally Lipschitz property from above.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you stating where $\lim_{n \to \infty}t_n = t_0$ or asking if any sequence $t_n$ will converge to $t_0$?

Comment: I meant: for any sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_{n}=t_{0}$